# How do I write data to a volume locked with FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME?

Tags: windows, winapi, usb

If we lock the volume of USB drive using `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` control code functionality, can we get access to  this locked volume, means is it possible to write binary file to that locked volume?

Comment: I removed the Qt references since this is really a pure Win32 question

Comment: Please give me some example codes to do this...

Comment: Example codes for what? You already have the handle. It's what you used when you passed `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` to `DeviceIoControl`. So are you saying that you don't know how to call `WriteFile`? You also need to think about what it means to write directly to the volume. You understand that this bypasses the file system right? And so your volume will not be readable unless you write your own file system code.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` you must already have open a handle to the volume by your call to `CreateFile`. Use `WriteFile`, passing that same volume handle, to write data to the volume.

Answer (score 0):

No, when a volume is locked the file system on that volume is unavailable.